# Wheel not built when pip installing from source - causes ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pip

I have written a python package `mypackage` , hosted on github, that I now want to install as a dependency to another project (specifically branch `branch`).

I can build it locally using setuptools and a pyproject.toml file by running `python3 -m pip install .` at the top of `mypackage/` and can then successfully import it into python.

I pushed this to github and now try to install it using

```
python3 -m pip install "git+https://github.com/mygituser/mypackage.git@branch"
```

This runs without warning, and if I then run `python3 -m pip list` I can see `mypackage` listed there. However, if I enter python and run `import mypackage` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`.

Comparing the verbose outputs I can see that for the local install after installing the dependencies I get

```
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running egg_info
  writing mypackage/mypackage.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to mypackage/mypackage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
...
...
```

etc. which is absent for the github build process (this just ends after dependencies are installed).

Am I missing a setting in pyproject.toml or somewhere to tell it to build a wheel so I can `import mypackage` it in python?

I have tried appending with `#egg=mypackage` and adding `wheel` to the build dependencies, but none of this has worked.

TIA

Comment: Can you provide a link to your github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/jatkinson1000/archeryutils I am specifically trying to build the branch 'classifications'

Comment: I just updated the pyproject.toml changing the find organisation and am now making some progress (data files not found so seems to be a me problem now).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes you made to your pyprojcet.toml file here: https://github.com/jatkinson1000/archeryutils/commit/f5fb491aa37961a65796ce4be3616d8be23548ed

You also need to include a __init__.py file in your round_data_files folder so it gets included in the package install.

https://github.com/jatkinson1000/archeryutils/pull/9